# Convert php array of items to hierarchical array if has a parent id

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP array like this:

```
<?php $pages = array (
    'home' => array (
        'title' => 'Home Page',
        'slug' => 'home-page'
    ),

    'contact' => array (
        'title' => 'Contact',
        'slug' => 'contact-page'
    ),

    'project' => array (
        'title' => 'Project',
        'slug' => 'project-page',
        'parent' => 'contact'
    ),

    'analytics' => array (
        'title' => 'Analytics',
        'slug' => 'analytics-page',
        'parent' => 'contact'
    ),

    'apps' => array (
        'title' => 'Apps',
        'slug' => 'apps-page',
        'parent' => 'analytics'
    )
); ?>
```

That I need to convert to be structured like this as a multi-dimensional array:

```
<?php $pages = array (
    'home' => array (
        'title' => 'Home Page',
        'slug' => 'home-page'
    ),

    'contact' => array (
        'title' => 'Contact',
        'slug' => 'contact-page',
        'children' => array(
            'portfolio' => array (
                'title' => 'Portfolio',
                'slug' => 'portfolio-page',
            ),

            'analytics' => array (
                'title' => 'Analytics',
                'slug' => 'analytics-page',
                'parent' => 'contact',
                'children' => array(
                    'apps' => array (
                        'title' => 'Apps',
                        'slug' => 'apps-page',
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
); ?>
```

I've tried this PHP code but it only converts it to a one dimensional array:

```
<?php $formatted_pages = array();
foreach ($pages as $key => $page) {
    if ( $page['parent'] ) {
        $formatted_pages[ $page['parent'] ]['children'][$key]['title'] = $page['title'];
        $formatted_pages[ $page['parent'] ]['children'][$key]['slug'] = $page['slug'];
    } else {
        $formatted_pages[] = array(
            'title' => $page['title'],
            'slug' => $page['slug']
        );
    }
} ?>
```

I'm not sure of a solution to make it iterate at any level no matter how many levels the array is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
`$pages = array (
    'home' => array (
        'title' => 'Home Page',
        'slug' => 'home-page'
    ),

    'contact' => array (
        'title' => 'Contact',
        'slug' => 'contact-page'
    ),

    'project' => array (
        'title' => 'Project',
        'slug' => 'project-page',
        'parent' => 'contact'
    ),

    'analytics' => array (
        'title' => 'Analytics',
        'slug' => 'analytics-page',
        'parent' => 'contact'
    ),

    'apps' => array (
        'title' => 'Apps',
        'slug' => 'apps-page',
        'parent' => 'analytics'
    )
);

function makeItTree($pages = [], $parent = null ) {
    $roots = [];
    $search = [];

    foreach ($pages as $alias => $page){
        if(($page['parent'] ?? null) === $parent){
            $roots[$alias] = $page;
        } else {
            $search[$alias] = $page;
        }
    }

    foreach ($roots as $alias => &$root){
        $children = makeItTree($search, $alias);

        if(count($children)){
            $root['children'] = $children;
        }
    }

    return $roots;
}

var_dump(makeItTree($pages));`
```

Result will be like

`

```
array(2) {
  ["home"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(9) "Home Page"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(9) "home-page"
  }
  ["contact"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Contact"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(12) "contact-page"
    ["children"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["project"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(7) "Project"
        ["slug"]=>
        string(12) "project-page"
        ["parent"]=>
        string(7) "contact"
      }
      ["analytics"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(9) "Analytics"
        ["slug"]=>
        string(14) "analytics-page"
        ["parent"]=>
        string(7) "contact"
        ["children"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["apps"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["title"]=>
            string(4) "Apps"
            ["slug"]=>
            string(9) "apps-page"
            ["parent"]=>
            string(9) "analytics"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`